# Kylo installation using docker fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kylo

I followed the link to install kylo with other components mentioned in Docker file.

https://github.com/keven4ever/kylo_docker

But getting below error while running the docker.

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Need to understand where is the issue. I have tried the latest version of Kylo 0.9.0.1 also but getting the same error.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the Dockerfile and not with Kylo. Have you tried creating an issue in the GitHub repo? Kylo requires Java 8 and UnsupportedClassVersionError usually means you're using an older version of Java.

Comment: All versions as suggested in the link are correct. Java version is also 1.8.0_151. Tried with fresh installation as well but it didn't help. Would you mind sharing a correct docker file to proceed. That will be appriciated.

Comment: You might be able to find some on Docker Hub. Also, the company that makes Kylo, Think Big Analytics, provides Docker containers through their paid support program. I've not tried any of them though.

Comment: Also, could you provide the entire exception and the steps to reproduce?